# Display SQL Server data in Sharepoint with the ability to Drill Down

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

Metadata External List

1. Users need to see & update metadata information about user databases
   via sharepoint.
2. Users open a Sharepoint site and look for metadata
3. Information  Data being pulled from SQL server.
4. Could be a workflow or list or whatever … I do not know

Sample finished product:

Select your Server

[image]

this comes from a SQL database

```
SELECT Servers from ServersTable;


SELECT TableName from AllTables   
WHERE Server = A
```

[image]

This is the last screen here users should be able to add additonal comments 
(Which means an Insert query for AllTables Table should be ran)

I tried creating an external list and pull Server names from a view that I created, but I do not know how to proceed forward, when I server list is displayed can I make it clickable and when clicked it runs a Stored procedure and display the results etc